# Can Jenkins (continuous build) pinpoint the commit that caused a build failure?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins says a build succeeded or failed, but can it identify the exact commit (and author!) that caused a build to fail?

[This issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12972) would seem to indicate no.

**Edit**: From my exchange with Pace:

> What I see is "include culprits", which is everyone since the last
>   build. I don't want that. I want THE culprit, with Jenkins doing the
>   binary search. If Jenkins does two builds 10 commits apart, I don't
>   want 10 possible culprits, I want it to find **the one**.

I haven't yet heard how to do that.

Comment: hey did you find any solution for this? I was wondering if there is Machine Learning based solution...that may be uses the files in commit.. to predict the culprit commit.

Answer (score 3):

That page was talking about the "find bugs" plugin, not the normal build cycle.  Depending on how things are setup Jenkins can identify the exact commit and author that caused a failure.  If Jenkins has the appropriate source control plugins installed and is configured to know about the repository the build is tied to then for every build it will list the changes since the last build.

In addition, Jenkins has the capability in many of its reporting plugins to blame the faulty committer.  It can, for example, send an [e-mail notification](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/E-mail-notifications-to-individuals-who-broke-the-build-td364556.html) on a failed build to the developer that made the faulty commit.

However, many setups make it difficult for Jenkins to know.  For example, if Jenkins is configured for daily builds then there are likely many commits which could have caused the issue.  It's also possible that Jenkins isn't configured to know about the source control repository, or there is no source control repository.  All of these issues could cause Jenkins to be unable to identify the build breaker.

Specifically for e-mailing faulty committers you can use the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin which has options to send e-mails to everyone that committed since the last successful build.

For a humorous take on this subject check out [this approach](http://www.papercut.com/blog/chris/2011/08/19/who-broke-the-build/).

Comment: I know little about Jenkins docs and have been casting about for awhile.  Can you point me to docs that say how to configure Jenkins to identify the exact commit?  Based on what I see (configured by someone else), I'm sure it knows about our git repo.

Comment: The humorous take is nice, but it doesn't actually say how to configure Jenkins.  We don't need a nerf gun, just an email.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the "e-mail individuals who broke the build" option was part of standard Jenkins.  After talking with our build guy he says it came from the email-ext plugin.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I still don't see the option.  What I see is "include culprits", which is everyone since the last build.  I don't want that.  I want THE culprit, with Jenkins doing the binary search.  If Jenkins does two builds 10 commits apart, I don't want 10 possible culprits, I want it to find the one.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that.  No, Jenkins does not do that out of the box.  There might be a plugin that does that but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: In order to that you'd need to build on every commit.

Comment: I don't think this exists. You need to build on every commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is impossible in some cases. Determining who the culprit is requires insight into conflict resolution that only a human can decide. Even still, sometimes a manager has to be involved in order to arbitrate. Say for instance you get 3 commits (A,B,C) that depend on a preexisting definition. However, another commit (D) modifies the behavior of that function. Which do you revert? Perhaps it's the business plan to keep A,B,C as is and return D to its original state. The opposite, modifying A,B,C to adapt to the changes of D, is also possible.

In the cases where a machine can handle the arbitration, it is the responsibility of unit tests, and static analyzers, to determine the culprit (although still imperfect). Static analyzers sometimes have built in features that email the person who committed a violation. Unit tests can be written that notify teams or team members responsible for a failed test. Both could work in the same way that identifies who was the last committer on a particular line that failed. Still, if it is a problem with linking, then perhaps some members should be associated with the particular makefile.

Comment: I'm not looking into this anymore, but the first commit that broke the build is a well-defined concept.  Whether that build is solely to blame is more complicated, but at least the simple thing should be deliverable by a computer.